# How can i join or implode the below array code?

Tags: php, sql

In the below code i want to join or implode all arrays of $trackersurl in a single line. i am getting the results in different lines, so i want to join in a single line.
Can anyone help me out?

I am searching results in stackoverflow, but could not follow.

My code is in below:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM announce WHERE torrent = $id ORDER BY seeders DESC";
$query = @mysql_query($sql);
while ($result  = @mysql_fetch_array($query)) {

$trackersurl1 = $result['url'];
$trackersurl2 = "&tr=".$trackersurl1;
$trackersurl = array($trackersurl2);

}
```

Results of [var.trackersurl] in html page is below:

```
&tr=http:ajgdsjhg/ann
&tr=udp://iuysidfu/ann
&tr=udp:wutefghgw/ann
&tr=http://sdhgsjdhgj/ann
```

I want to join them in a single line below

```
&tr=http:ajgdsjhg/ann&tr=udp://iuysidfu/ann&tr=udp:wutefghgw/ann&tr=http://sdhgsjdhgj/ann
```

Comment: Please give an example how the resulting string should look like.

Comment: None of this code is actually 'outputting results'.

Comment: be more specific about what you want to achieve?

Comment: please check back the question now

Comment: Edit the question and try to explain what you want to do. Unless community cant understand, how it can help.

Comment: Add a line after while loop `echo '<pre>';print_r($tracker);echo '</pre>';` which will clear what the original array is, then it will be easy to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be careful of sql injection.

Are you looking to create an array['trackers'] with a string of all the trackers for a magnet link?

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM announce WHERE torrent = ".mysql_real_escape_string($id)." ORDER BY seeders DESC";
$query = mysql_query($sql);

$tracker = null;
if(mysql_num_rows($query)>=1){
    while ($result  = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
        $tracker .= "&tr=".$result['url'];
    }
}
$tracker = array('trackers'=>$tracker);

//$tracker['trackers'] = "&tr=a.com&tr=b.com&tr=c.com";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
$newArray=array();
while ($result  = @mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    $trackersurl1 = $result['title'];
    $newArray[] = "&tr=".$trackersurl1;
}
$urlString=implode('',$newArray);
```